# What's this brown spot on my jade leaf?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, leaves, succulents, jade

What's this brown spot on the leaf of my jade plant? I first saw it on the leaf about a week ago. A few days before I saw it, I had to remove one of its bottom leaves because it looked like it was rotting. I'm an amateur plant parent, but I'm thinking it could be overwatering, root rot, pests... What do you think it is?

I'm super attached to this jade baby because it's the first plant I ever propagated, so I hope that whatever it is, it's fixable!

[image: Small Jade plant with a brown spot on a leaf, near the stem.]

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell, but it doesn't look like a very concerning spot. The rest of the plant looks very healthy. Often, brown spots on Jade has to do with a watering issue. Here are some tips:

- Don't over water. Allow the soil to dry between watering. If you're concerned that you over-watered, carefully dig up the plant and check for root rot. The roots should be firm, not soggy or slimy.
- If water gets on the leaves of the jade, keep it out of direct sunlight. Water on leaves will catch the sun and create burns. When watering your plant, pour water at the base of the plant, not over top.
- Jade loves direct sun, but it can burn easily if it's not used to it. You can build up it's sun tolerance by increasing how much sun it gets a little bit each week.
- Jade prefers dry, not humid, air. It helps the soil dry out and helps prevent rot.

For more things to look into, check out [this guide](https://smartgardenguide.com/jade-plant-leaves-turning-brown/) about diagnosing brown spots on Jade plants.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the link!